# "lpwd " and "lcd path" command not found on PUTTY

Tags: putty, lcd

please help me! I need to transfer the file from PC to Elektra (PUTTY). I want to see the local working directory before I transfer the file, but when I typed "lpwd ", it showed that "command not found" on the screen. Then I tried to move to a new local directory by using "lcd path", but it didn't work neither. Anyone knows why it happened? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY is not made for transferring files between Windows and *nix boxes. You want to check out an application such as [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

When you use PuTTY, it's running commands on a remote server, ignoring that's you're on Windows or another OS. `lcd`, `lpwd`, et al are for when you are in an FTP session - The FTP server is well aware it's being used remotely. Even then, the commands running locally (`lpwd` and such) are part of your FTP *client*, not the server, which is why in the same screen, you'll see the effects on your local system.